# weird result from regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string '10H30M2D3I2M10S', and want to separate the string into 3 pieces, like this ['10H', '20M2D3I2M', '10S'], I write a python regex as follows,

```
import re

cigar = '10H30M2D2N2=2X3I2M10S'
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+[HS])*((\d+[MIDNP=X])+)(\d+[HS])*')
r = pattern.search(cigar)
print(r.groups())
```

the result is ('10H', '30M2D2N2=2X3I2M', '2M', '10S')

this result seems weird, anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** rewritten, since my previous answer was totally wrong...

You're close, but you need to make your internal group, `\d+[MIDNP=X]`, to be non-capturing:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+[HS])*((?:\d+[MIDNP=X])+)(\d+[HS])*')
```

This will give you only 3 groups, with the second one covering the whole inside string.  Otherwise, the way your code has it, you had an extra capturing group that only captured the last.  The way I previously proposed it ( `(\d+[HS])*(\d+[MIDNP=X])+(\d+[HS])*` ), would not give you the capturing group that captures everything from the `+`.

[Here](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cd%2B%5BHS%5D)*((%3F%3A%5Cd%2B%5BMIDNP%3DX%5D)%2B)(%5Cd%2B%5BHS%5D)*&test_string=10H30M2D2N2%3D2X3I2M10S&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) is an example of the working python regex.

Comment: Thank you! I also want the '30M2D2N2=2X3I2M' to be matched and captured, your pattern gives ['10H', '2M', '10S'], which is not the desired result.